# How to evaluate decision boundaries for KNeighborsRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, knn

I have come across codes and articles on using KNeighborsClassifier for evaluating decision boundaries.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_regression.html 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/how-to-plot-decision-boundary-of-a-k-nearest-neighbor-classifier-from-elements-o

How can decision boundaries be implemented for KNeighborsRegressor after training in python using scikit-learn?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a conceptual missunderstanding. There is nothing like a decision boundary in a regression problem (only an approximated function). If you want to plot the latter follow the example in the second link you posted. Train the Regressor on the data and then predict every point in a certain interval. In the example this is done by:

```py
T = np.linspace(0, 5, 500)[:, np.newaxis]
```

and

```
y_ = knn.fit(X, y).predict(T)
```